# Volley Content-Type not changing on Certain phones

Tags: android, api, android-volley, content-type

I am using volley and JsonArrayAuthRequest to get an api. The api works on some of my phones, but it fails on another person's (Both using api level 23, marshmellow)

The error message that they are getting is "400" The request is badly formed. It shows the Content="text/html;charset=us-ascii". However, I know the expected entity is json/application.

I tried overriding the getHeaders() and getBodyContentType().. Any ideas?

```
    String baseUrl = Constants.constants.getApiUrl() +"Events/";
    String url = baseUrl + query;
    //Log.i("url",url);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    JsonArrayAuthRequest eventRequest = new JsonArrayAuthRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
                            .disable(FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES); // fails if not 1 to 1 mapping
                    ArrayList<Event> data = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); ++i) {
                        Object res;
                        try {
                            res = response.get(i);
                            //Log.i("res", res.toString()); //grabs the filtered events already
                            Event e = mapper.readValue(res.toString(), Event.class);
                            data.add(e);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.d("error", e.toString());
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    //Log.i("Browse", "got " + Integer.toString(data.size()) + " events!");

                    browse = (BrowseFragment) adapter.getItem(0);
                    browse.setData(data);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if (error == null || error.networkResponse == null) {
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.show();
                        return;
                    }
                    String errorMessage = "Could not stringify errorMessage";
                    try {
                         errorMessage = new String(error.networkResponse.data,"UTF-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.networkResponse.statusCode + ": " + errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();

                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                }
            });
    queue.add(eventRequest)
 }


private class JsonArrayAuthRequest extends JsonArrayRequest {
        JsonArrayAuthRequest(String url, Response.Listener<JSONArray> 
listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
            super(url, listener, errorListener);
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("account", MODE_PRIVATE);
            headers.put("Authorization", UserInfo.User.getToken());
            //Log.i("headers",headers.get("Content-Type") + " " + headers.get("Authorization"));
            return headers;
        }
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType()
        {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a content-type error. The real error was the api url included a space which was causing the 400 error. My phone must have cached a previous url?? Not sure.. But I have been looking in the wrong direction for this solution..